# MySQL continue after Duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql

I'm running a 'bash for' script to update some records in mysql, like so:

`` for i in `cat yahoo.txt`; do mysql $DB --batch -fe "update users set email=concat(left(email, instr(email, '@')), 'yahoo.com') where email like '%@$i';" ; done ``

but even with --force, the update stops after the first error:

`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry 'example@yahoo.com' for key 3`

Is there anyway I can force it to continue?

Comment: What leads you to believe it isn't continuing?  That script should do fine, unless your shell has been interestingly configured.

Comment: I do a select for the mistyped emails (before and after executing the script) and the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing *update* to *update ignore*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html :

> With the IGNORE keyword, the update statement does not abort even if
>   errors occur during the update. Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts
>   occur are not updated. Rows for which columns are updated to values
>   that would cause data conversion errors are updated to the closest
>   valid values instead.

Comment: thank you! didn't had a clue that option existed.

Comment: there's also insert ignore - skips the inserts for the cases where item with identical value [for primary key, unique indices] already exists.